# Haskell: Undefined variable in (String, String) | undefined type?

Tags: variables, haskell, dictionary, types, undefined

So, still working on this Dictionary task. My problem now is: The File actually compiles, but as soon as a I want to insert something with

```
insert dict (Hilfe, help)
```

I get an error, which, in this case, would read (undefined variable "hello")
However, insert has (String, String) defined in a tuple, so this is something I don't understand and literally have no idea how to fix.

Apart from that, I also tried to use :t on Dictionary, however it told me that the data constructor is undefined. As soon as I added a data Dictionary line to the file, it wouldn't compile because Dictionary is multiply defined. 
So, is this a question of either / or, and not both? Because something seems fishy.

```
type Dictionary = [(String, String)]

dict :: Dictionary
dict = []

insert :: Dictionary -> (String,String) -> Dictionary
insert dict (deu, eng) = (deu, eng):dict
```

Pardon my fast asking of seemingly simple questions. This here I really tried to work around to no avail, and with our very very lackluster introduction to functional programming,  I'm pretty sure there's just some mistake I'm unable to find. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Haskell have quote marks around them.  If you want to insert strings you need to put quote marks around them.

```
insert dict ("Hilfe", "help")
```

You can only use `:t` to find the type of an expression.  You can't do `:t Dictionary` because `Dictionary` *is* a type.

Comment: Hooooly, of course I forgot the quotation marks. ._. Thanks for stating the obvious to me, I'm dumb. :D

Answer (score 0):

By the way: If patten `(deu, eng)` is not needed, you could just use 1 variable:

```
insert :: Dictionary -> (String,String) -> Dictionary
insert dict word = word : dict
```